# Java EE - form authentication - how do I bypass the login during development?

Tags: jsf, authentication, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I'm building a Java EE web application using JSF, Netbeans and Glassfish. I just built a standard form login for my application. The problem is that now every time I deploy the project, which is very frequent, it clears the authentication and I have to log in again.

I am new to Java EE so it is possible that this is a configuration problem, but from what I read this is normal behavior.

During the development cycle, what methods are there to handle this? I could disable the authentication during development but that just doesn't seem like a "good" solution.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on how you're doing the authentication. So, tell that in detail then.

Answer (score 0):

I had an epiphany about my problem. The simple answer is Test Driven Development.

I found myself developing by making a change to my application. Clean, Compile, and Deploy to Glassfish. I was finding this increasingly frustrating because of how slow that process is. In addition, I'm new to JavaEE development so I am working in small incremental steps.

The epiphany came when I saw and remembered reading about Test Driven Development from Kent Beck. I only made it to Chapter 6 but shelved it as other books took higher priority at the time. Now it's time to read it.

I highly recommend reading the book. Basically, the process is to build your unit tests first and use them to build the application.

Here is a link to the book I'm reading: [http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-Kent-Beck/dp/0321146530/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1324507172&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530)